# While-Loop and displaying barcode as output

Tags: java, while-loop, fractions

This program is supposed to display a series of fractions (determined by the user) that calculates the total. It won't let me enter fractions into the program only the number of them which it says is invalid typically.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fractions
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        //------------------ declare ints and constants ----
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int     fractions       = 0,
            count           = 1,
            fractionAdd     = 0;

        double  enteredFraction = 0;

        boolean inValid = false;
        //------------------- welcome msg -----------------------
        System.out.println("\n * * * Welcome to Fractions * * *\n");

        //--------------------- get input ----------------------
        System.out.print("Enter the number of fractions: ");
        fractions = stdIn.nextInt();

        if (fractions < 2 && fractions > 10)
            inValid = true;
        else
            inValid = true;

        while (inValid)
        {
            System.out.print(
                fractions + " is invalid, please re-enter ractions (2-10):  "
            );

            fractions = stdIn.nextInt();

            if (fractions < 2 && fractions > 10)
                inValid = true;

            else
                inValid = false;

        }
        while (count < fractions)
        {
            System.out.println(fractions + "+");
            fractions += count;

            while (fractions < count)
            {
                System.out.print(enteredFraction + " +");
                fractions ++;
            }

            if(enteredFraction <= fractions)
                System.out.println("Error, please re-enter number of fractions (2-10)");

        }

        //--------------------- end msg ---------------------------
        System.out.println("\nThanks for using the Fraction Adder program");

    } //end main
}//end program
```

Comment: Can you share your output and add details about what exactly the problem is.

Comment: you wrote `else inValid = true;` but surely you meant to put false there. also, inValid being false is a double negative... you should rename to just "valid"

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (fractions < 2 && fractions > 10)
        inValid = true;
    else
        inValid = true;
```

I think problem is here.
You set 'inValid' flag in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `fractions += count;` to `fractions += count;` and also

```
if (fractions < 2 && fractions > 10)
            inValid = true;
        else
            inValid = true;
```

is always `true` you must change it to `inValid = fractions < 2 && fractions > 10;`